# Freestyle Line Style noise modifier not working

Tags: freestyle

*Solved.* I recently started learning Blender and I was playing with the Freestyle option with Suzanne. I would like to achieve a "hand-drawn" effect, so I added a 2D offset type modifier to Freestyle Line Style and a noise modifier to each of its parameters. The idea is that the lines should change a little over time. The problem is that the parameters are not affected by the noise and I cannot find the error. The rendered images are always the same, am i forgetting something?

My file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bS_uk2HDjP6GwhqvwVlYHEG8E4wmzQq1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution. If anyone encounters the same problem, try installing Blender v. 2.82. I was using 2.81a, it seems it was a bug.